# Prediction using location data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I a trying to develop a part of code that helps me predict the productivity of a new resource in a bank based on the existing productivity i.e(No of accounts opened in past 12 months/ 12 months) of existing resources in a particular city branch within the bank.For example if I want to hire a new resource in Agra, the model can suggest me the existing productivity in Agra branch.

Below is a link of my python notebook.
[Notebook](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/1fafb792-5b7e-479b-a14b-908fe63644b6/view?access_token=2450afbebf3f8094e4999f2a576c3fc800c6b9fc543193153a7fccc032d9c34c)

I have tried KNN model to forecast the data, however the accuracy of model is very low.

Would there be a better way to predict the data given the Branch name or its location co-ordinates?

I am using Python 3.6 notebook

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; please post what you have tried so far, and the specific issues encountered. Nobody can do anything with nothing but a screenshot of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut. I have edited the question and attached a copy of my notebook. I am not able to get good accuracy for KNN algorithm. Can you please look through the code and suggest how can I improve the prediction accuracy.

Comment: Please see how to create a [MCVE]; code is supposed to be included here, and not to some external repo.

Comment: Sure, will ensure the same moving forward.

Comment: @desertnaut I do appreciate your help, but it is not absolutely binding on me to accept "only your" answer. I will await if any form member has better inputs to add for the query. Trust you understand.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, you still expect answers while your linked external notebook "is currently not shared?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to predict a numeric output, so your problem is a **regression**, *not* a classification one. Classifiers won't do the job, neither accuracy is the correct performance measure here.

You need to use a performance metric appropriate for regression - see the [list in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values); assuming you want to use mean absolute error (MAE), you should change your training loop to:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

#Train Model and Predict  
neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = n).fit(X_train,y_train)
yhat=neigh.predict(X_test)
err[n-1] = mean_absolute_error(y_test, yhat)
```

and keep in mind that MAE is an error metric, i.e. the lower the better, and you have predefined `err` in a manner similar to your `mean_acc`,